# jquery dropdown menu opens repeatedly upon hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a bit of a problem with a jquery menu. I works just fine, but if you hover over the buttons 3 or 4 times, the menu will expand 3 or 4 times repetitively, and all you can do it wait for it to quit. Can somebody please tell me how to stop this? Here's the javascript I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
      $('#dropMenu .level1 .submenu.submenu').hover(function() {
$(this).find('ul.level2,.level3 li,.level4 li,.level5 li,.level6 li').stop(true, true).hide(1000);
$(this).find('ul.level2,.level3 li,.level4 li,.level5 li,.level6 li').stop(true, true).show(1000);
}, function() {
$(this).find('ul.level2,.level3 li,.level4 li,.level5 li,.level6 li').stop(true, true).show(1000);
$(this).find('ul.level2,.level3 li,.level4 li,.level5 li,.level6 li').stop(true, true).hide(1000);
});});
</script>
```

Any insight to this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you attach the relevant markup too?

Answer (score 2):

Hey Robert, I hate when a simple hover action does unexpected results. 
Over time I've developed a few methods to resolving the flicking of elements.

Assuming you have a menu structure like so;

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="...">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="...">New Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">All Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">Specials</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">Search</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="...">Site</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS something like this;

```
<style>
  #nav ul li ul{
    display:none;
  }
</style>
```

jQuery something like this;

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#nav ul li").each(function(){
    $(this).mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).find("ul:first").show();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).find("ul:first").hide();
    });
  })
</script>
```

Notice, I'm using `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseexit()` instead of `.hover()` in this example.

Why `.hover()` doesn't do what you expect in this example? 
Hover only works on a single element, when you hover on something within the element, it's a new element.

A great example is on [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter#example-0)

I hope this clears up your Hover issues.

Comment: Hey, halfcube.....I'll sure give a try later. I think for now, we've decided to go with the FadIn and FadeOut, which seems to be working very nicely. I'm always looking for things like this though, and I know for sure, I've got more projects coming up that will use the same dropdown menu. Thank you so much for your time and answer. I'll let you know if it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable to indicate when an animation is active and don't allow another one to start, if the previous one hasn't finished.

```
var isAnimating = false;
$(function () {
      $('#dropMenu .level1 .submenu.submenu').hover(function() {
if (!isAnimating) {
  $(this).find('ul.level2,.level3 li,.level4 li,.level5 li,.level6 li').stop(true, true).hide(1000);
  $(this).find('ul.level2,.level3 li,.level4 li,.level5 li,.level6 li').stop(true, true).show(1000);
  isAnimating = true;
}
}, function() {
$(this).find('ul.level2,.level3 li,.level4 li,.level5 li,.level6 li').stop(true, true).show(1000);
$(this).find('ul.level2,.level3 li,.level4 li,.level5 li,.level6 li').stop(true, true).hide(1000);
isAnimating = false;
});});
```